# How can I make purchase with RevenueCat by Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, revenuecat

How can I make a purchase using RevenueCat v6.0.0 by Kotlin, I can see in their [Docs](https://www.revenuecat.com/docs/making-purchases) :

```
Purchases.sharedInstance.purchaseWith(
  PurchaseParams.Builder(this, aPackage).build(),
  onError = { error, userCancelled -> /* No purchase */ },
  onSuccess = { storeTransaction, customerInfo ->
    if (customerInfo.entitlements["my_entitlement_identifier"]?.isActive == true) {
      // Unlock that great "pro" content
    }
  }
)
```

But Unfortunately I can't create this (aPackage) variable, for example if I have a product ID named: "monthly_sub", How can I get it and then pass it in this method (purchaseWith)?

I've tried to apply the docs and expect it to open Google Play paywall to make the purchase.